# Insert into multiple tables with shared keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, import, insert

I need to insert multiple users and phonenumbers into a phonebook. I have the users and their phonenumbers in a .csv file, and I need to add this data to multiple tables that share a FK uniqeidentifier. The identifier is generated upon creating a user in the User-table.

1. How can I achieve this?
2. How can I achieve this in the most
   efficient way possible?

What I've tried and what I would like to do (but that does not work):

```sql
CREATE TABLE Users(
UserID uniqeidentifier NOT NULL  
   DEFAULT newid(),
Firstname nvarchar (25),
Lastname nvarchar(25)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Phonebook(
Number nvarchar (25),
UserID uniqeidentifier
)
GO

CREATE TABLE #TempImportedUsers(
firstname nvarchar(25),
lastname nvarchar(25),
phonenumber nvarchar(25)
)
GO

BULK INSERT #TempImportedUsers
    FROM 'D:\import.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    Tablock
    )
    GO

INSERT INTO Users (Firstname, Lastname)
OUTPUT #TempImportedUsers.phonenumber,Inserted.UserID INTO Phonebook(Number, UserID)
SELECT
    firstname,
    lastname
FROM
    #TempImportedUsers
```

Content of D:\import.csv:

```
Firstname,Lastname,Number
Foo,Bar,3311664499
Baz,Qux,8844331166
```

Obviously the above won't work because of the `OUTPUT #TempImportedUsers.phonenumber,Inserted.UserID INTO Phonebook(Number, UserID)` is invalid.

How can I achieve this import? Do I have to use cursors?

Comment: Is this a one time import or something you need to do repeatedly. Either way this would be a lot easier if you have a column in your temp table as a primary key.

Comment: I could definitly add a column to the temp table if you believe that would help. I dont see how that would help though, as the imported data in the *.csv wont contain any key. If I could do like "UPDATE #temptable SET id" based on the OUTPUT clause I could see the point, but I dont think that's possible.
 Please give a code example if you have anything in mind.

Comment: Or are you suggesting that I create my own uniqeidentifier for each user in the temptable, then use that identifier to add user and phonenumber to their tables?
I guess that could work, unless theres any potential downside to generate my own identifiers in a #temptable?

Comment: I don't know that I would use a uniqueidentifier. That seems a bit overkill unless you are going to persist that into your table. I can't really "give a code" because there isn't much definition here. No tables, sample data etc...

Comment: @SeanLange My thought was to persist that into the actual tables, yes.
I've edited my question to contain sample data as well, the tables where there from start. 
Let me know if you need any further information to be able to propose a solution.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Yeah using a uniqueidentifier here would be an easy solution. Just add that column as NULL to your table prior to insert with a default of NEWID. You will need to create a formatfile for this to work correctly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-skip-a-table-column-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: **Note:** Using a `uniqueindetifier` as your clustered index might result with a cluster index that is heavily fragmented, causing a performance problem when selecting data from the table. If you must use a `uniqueidentifier` as your primary key, the least you should do is generate it using `newSequentialId()` instead of simply `newId()`, which should result with much less fragmentation on your clustered index.

Comment: Thanks @ZoharPeled. I dont think newSequentialId() would be approriate for a couple of reasons:
I have no control of the design of the "User" and "Phonebook"-tables (the database is provided by an external application) so I cannot change the way IDs are generated there.
The reason newId() is used is so that you cannot "guess" the next ID based on a sequence.
Also users could be created at any time from client PC and web applications. I'm not sure what would happen if I import a large number of users into #temptable with sequentialId at the same time a user is created from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it was suggested in the comments it dawned on me that an easy fix is to generate my own Guid/uniqeidentifier since thats whats being used in the Users and Phonebook-tables anyway.

Just in case there would be any duplicated guids, I wrapped it all in a BEGIN TRANSACTION-statement to handle a rollback of the entire import.
And finally select the imported users and drop the #temptable.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TempImportedUsers(
firstname nvarchar(25),
lastname nvarchar(25),
phonenumber nvarchar(25),
guid uniqueidentifier DEFAULT newid()
)
GO

BULK INSERT #TempImportedUsers
    FROM 'D:\import.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    Tablock
    )
    GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
    BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO Users (Firstname, Lastname, UserID)
SELECT
    firstname,
    lastname,
    guid
FROM
    #TempImportedUsers

INSERT INTO Phonebook(Number, UserID)
SELECT
    number,
    guid
FROM
    #TempImportedUsers
COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1]
    END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1]
END CATCH

SELECT * FROM #TempImportedUsers
DROP TABLE #TempImportedUsers
```

The import.csv is updated to supply a NULL value for the new #temptable column:

```
Firstname,Lastname,Number,Guid
Foo,Bar,3311664499,
Baz,Qux,8844331166,
```

In my original question I asked 2 questions; how to achieve this and how to do it the most efficent manner.
This solves how to achieve it, but I don't know if there are more efficent ways (resource efficency or number of written lines) - so I'll leave the question open for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the system to get this done by placing the UserID generation into your #temp table. Here is an example of the import below,

The simplest way to do this is to use `OPENROWSET(bulk, ...)` instead of bulk insert, and use a temp table.  For this example, here is the temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempImportedUsers(
    UserId uniqueIdentifier DEFAULT NEWID(),
    firstname nvarchar(25),
    lastname nvarchar(25),
    phonenumber nvarchar(25)
);
```

And here is the relevant format file (XML format is the easiest way):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\n" MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="firstname" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="lastname" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="phonenumber" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

This XML format file has a trick - it ignores Column 1 of the table. This results in the auto-generated UUID generation.

Here is the sample file I used:

```
First,Last,Phone
Bob,Smith,333-444-6666
Bill,Smith,222-333-5555
Alice,Restaurant,91-03045-2222
```

And this was the INSERT query to load the #temp table:

```
INSERT INTO #TempImportedUsers (firstname, lastname, phonenumber)
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(bulk 'D:\import.csv',
formatfile='D:\formatfile.xml', FIRSTROW=2) as t;
```

The results of a `SELECT * FROM #TempImportedUsers` query were:

```
|UserId                              |firstname|lastname  |phonenumber  |
|------------------------------------|---------|----------|-------------|
|9514B27F-1C6B-4B18-BE63-4E7744B9484B|Bob      |Smith     |333-444-6666 |
|108AA33C-829B-4E7E-BE62-C88F1F77853A|Bill     |Smith     |222-333-5555 |
|9C6AD6FD-6F26-471E-A9B8-CE5F8F4B1266|Alice    |Restaurant|91-03045-2222|
```

Hopefully, this will help.

Comment: Haha you beat me by 23 seconds to pretty much the same solution!

However, in what I ended up using I just supply a NULL value to the UserID in #temptable and let the DEFAULT newid() generate a new id. Still using bulk insert, no extra xml.
Is there any pros/cons to the two different aproaches?

Comment: The only significant difference is that the CSV doesn't need to be modified when using the XML version.